# Error on delete Metadata List View

Tags: metadata-api, list-view

I'm trying to delete List Views using the [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) and I'm getting the following error.

Error occured processing component CustomObject__c.MyListView. In field: members - no ListView named CustomObject__c.MyListView found (INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY).

I'm trying to do that through a partner organization. I'm following the [guidelines](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_deleteMetadata.htm), and I think there is a permission needed to be granted that I didn't catch yet, because from my developer organization the same code works perfect.

There is my code:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = MetaDataJob.createService();     
List<MetadataService.DeleteResult> results =        
        service.deleteMetadata(
            'ListView', new String[] { 'CustomObject__c.MyListView' });
MetaDataJob.handleDeleteResults(results[0]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue on the MetaData API Repo on git hub and the owner of the project helped me to get an solution. 
There is the [answer](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/issues/86).